# Convert integer/decimal to hex on an Arduino?

Tags: arduino

How can an integer or decimal variable be converted into a hex string? I can do the opposite (convert hex to int) but I can't figure out the other way.

This is for `Serial.print()` hex values in an array.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take a look at the Arduino String tutorial [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors). The code below was taken from that example.

```
// using an int and a base (hexadecimal):
stringOne =  String(45, HEX);   
// prints "2d", which is the hexadecimal version of decimal 45:
Serial.println(stringOne);
```

There are plenty of other examples on that page, though I think for floating point numbers you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Just confirming what Nathan said about floating points. The code base to support printing out floating points is considered too large to be included by default. A simple solution is to multiply your number by 100 or so and print it as an int.

Answer (score 10):

There's a simple solution, just use:

```
Serial.print(yourVariable, HEX);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Streaming](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/) library provides a built in way to do this:

```
#include <Streaming.h>
...
Serial << "45 in hex is " << _HEX(45) << endl;
```

You will need to download the Library from http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/ and place it in a subdirectory of your Sketchbook folder. The Menu File-Preferences will show you where that is.

This library can also be used when outputting to LCDs.