# How to convert a String to a char * in Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, arduino

I'm doing a function to convert an integer into a hexadecimal char * in Arduino, but I came across the problem of not being able to convert a String to a char *. Maybe if there is a way to allocate memory dynamically for char * I do not need a class String.

```
char *ToCharHEX(int x)
{
    String s;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 1;
    do
    {

        if (x > 16)
        {
            y = (x - (x % 16)) / 16;
            z = (x - (x % 16));
            x = x - (x - (x % 16));
        }
        else
        {
            y = x;
        }
        switch (y)
        {
        case 0:
            s += "0";
            continue;
        case 1:
            s += "1";
            continue;
        case 2:
            s += "2";
            continue;
        case 3:
            s += "3";
            continue;
        case 4:
            s += "4";
            continue;
        case 5:
            s += "5";
            continue;
        case 6:
            s += "6";
            continue;
        case 7:
            s += "7";
            continue;
        case 8:
            s += "8";
            continue;
        case 9:
            s += "9";
            continue;
        case 10:
            s += "A";
            continue;
        case 11:
            s += "B";
            continue;
        case 12:
            s += "C";
            continue;
        case 13:
            s += "D";
            continue;
        case 14:
            s += "E";
            continue;
        case 15:
            s += "F";
            continue;
        }
    }while (x > 16 || y * 16 == z);
    char *c;
    s.toCharArray(c, s.length());
    Serial.print(c);
    return c;
}
```

The toCharArray () function is not converting the string to a char array. Serial.print (c) is returning empty printing. I do not know what I can do.

Comment: my_string.c_str() not work in Arduino IDE

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `y,z` the first time `int y;
    int z;
    while (x > 16 || y * 16 == z)` is executed?

Comment: my_string.data() or &my_string[0] which will get the pointer to the internal char array.

Comment: my_string.data() or &my_string[0] not work, the problem continues

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works with a normal hard-coded String object? (ie. removed the `while` logic and just tried converting a hard-coded string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert integer/decimal to hex on an Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702931/convert-integer-decimal-to-hex-on-an-arduino)

Comment: The String works perfectly returning hexadecimal value, the problem is in converting from String to char *

Comment: @MatheusToniolli - See my updated answer.

Comment: Read the title of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated: Your Question re: `String -> char*` conversion:**

`String.toCharArray(char* buffer, int length)` wants a character array  buffer and the size of the buffer.

Specifically - your problems here are that:

1. `char* c` is a pointer that is never initialized.
2. `length` is supposed be be the size of the buffer. The string knows how long it is.

So, a better way to run this would be:

```
char c[20];
s.toCharArray(c, sizeof(c));
```

Alternatively, you could initialize `c` with `malloc`, but then you'd have to `free` it later. Using the stack for things like this saves you time and keeps things simple.

Reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray

---

**The intent in your code:**

This is basically a duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5703349/1068537

See Nathan's linked answer:

```
// using an int and a base (hexadecimal):
stringOne =  String(45, HEX);   
// prints "2d", which is the hexadecimal version of decimal 45:
Serial.println(stringOne);
```

Unless this code is needed for academic purposes, you should use the mechanisms provided by the standard libraries, and not reinvent the wheel.

- `String(int, HEX)` returns the hex value of the integer you're looking to convert
- `Serial.print` accepts `String` as an argument

Comment: My God! I know how to convert int to Hexadecimal, the problem is not that. I WANT TO CONVERT A String IN A char *.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* string2char(String command){
    if(command.length()!=0){
        char *p = const_cast<char*>(command.c_str());
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more info about your answer. Provide some explanation.